# How to configure custom ceph OSD options in ceph-ansible?

Tags: ansible

Currently I'm deploying a ceph cluster on a few ARM-based machines, namely the [HC2 from ODROID](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G151505170472) equipped with 4 TB WD Red Drives. I also found an article from [WD labs](https://ceph.com/geen-categorie/500-osd-ceph-cluster/), doing the same task at large scale (504 OSDs), suggesting to tune the OSD settings with

```
osd map cache size = 40
osd map max advance = 32
osd map message max = 32
```

Now I wonder (not only for that options alone), how to put them in the ansible group_vars or host vars, to accommodate the relatively low ressources on the HC2s.

Currently I believe, it is not possible with current ceph-ansible playbooks.

I would really appreciate, if someone can give me some hint on that. ceph-ansible does not seem to really use template files for the config (only as placeholders), so how could it be extended or tweaked to make these settings possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with the `ceph_conf_overrides` parameter (http://docs.ceph.com/ceph-ansible/master/#ceph-conf-configuration).

```
ceph_conf_overrides:
  osd:
    osd map cache size: 40
    osd map max advance: 32
    osd map message max: 32
```